# multiselect checkbox dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using multiselect checkbox dropdown.

Please look example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manthan11/qqhczbvs/6/)

```
$(function () { $('#lstStates').multiselect({ }); });
```

Once you select states it show then TEXT value and concat with comma like: New Jersey, New York, Ohio

But I want VALUE of that selected ITEM **like: NJ, NY, OH**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `buttonText` option of multiselect.

http://jsfiddle.net/ejqngpn5/

```
$('#lstStates').multiselect({ 
    buttonText: function(options, select) {
        console.log(select[0].length);
        if (options.length === 0) {
            return 'None selected';
        }
        if (options.length === select[0].length) {
            return 'All selected ('+select[0].length+')';
        }
        else if (options.length >= 4) {
            return options.length + ' selected';
        }
        else {
            var labels = [];
            console.log(options);
            options.each(function() {
                labels.push($(this).val());
            });
            return labels.join(', ') + '';
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: just make sure that you remove `console.log` statements if you don't use console-polyfill or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use **buttonText** option of multiSelect Plugin. The Parameter **options** give you all the option you select. Then format your buttonText value as you want.

**Script**

```
$(function () {
   $('#lstStates').multiselect({
      buttonText: function(options){
         if (options.length === 0) {
            return 'No option selected ...';
         }

         var labels = [];
         options.each(function() {
           if ($(this).attr('value') !== undefined) {
               labels.push($(this).attr('value'));
           } 
         });
        return labels.join(', ');  
     }
  }); 
});
```

Take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74b5pkpv/